# Force generic interface implementation in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

Is there anyway to force a constraints for a generic definition to implement a "generic interface" ... that is, I want the class to support passing an interface and a generic class constraining it so that the class implements the interface. For example if I say:

```
MyGenericClass<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>.DoSomething();
```

That should be constrained so that MyImplementation implements IMyInterface

As far as I know that can be achieved by

```
public class Dynamic_Loader<T, S> where S: T
```

Now, is there anyway to also force T to be an interface?

**Edit:** The purpose of this was to have something like:

```
private static List<T> interfaceList = new List<T>();

public static List<T> InterfaceList {get { return interfaceList;}}

public static void Add(S input) { interfaceList.Add(input);}
```

and have the list restricted to only interfaces (since it is supposed to return implementations of certain interfaces)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Do you mean, can a constraint also be put on `T` like `where T : interface`?**

If so, then **no**: [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) pretty much covers your options.

What you have is as close as it gets, I believe.

Out of curiosity, what would be your reason for wanting to constrain `T` to be an interface?

**Or do you mean can a constraint also be put on `T` for `T` to *implement* some *specific* interface?**

If so, then **yes**: simply have two `where` clauses (e.g., `where S : T where T : U`).

Comment: Oh, I was going for this:

public static List<T> interfacelist = new List<T>;

public static void Add(S input);

And yeah, it will work too if T is just a base class but the client should be getting interfaces, not base classes.

Comment: Here is one (probably edge case) scenario where I would use `where T : interface`.
In unity, there is a method TryGetComponent<T>(), where T is just an object, but when calling it, you get an error that 

> TryGetComponent should be called only with Types that extend UnityEngine.Component, or Types that are an Interface

So I need to specify one option for where T:UnityEngine.Component and second for any interface. Which is not possible at the moment

Answer (score 3):

```
where T: IMyOtherInterfaceForT
```

Example:

```
    public class Test<T, V>
    where T : V
    where V : IEnumerable<int>
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this to enforce it at runtime instead of compile time.

```
public class Test<T> where T : class
{
  public Test()
  {
    Type t = typeof( T );
    if( !t.IsInterface )
      throw new ArgumentException( "T must be an interface type" );
  }
}
```