# C#: How to force a generic type to be an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, polymorphism

The code below is valid:

```
public class Converter<T,M> : CustomCreationConverter<M>  
    where T : new()
    where M : class
```

However, this is what I would like to do:

```
public class Converter<T,M> : CustomCreationConverter<M>  
    where T : new()
    where M : interface
```

**Is something equivalent to this possible?**

A constraint that specified that T could be cast as M would also suffice in my specific circumstance.

To clarify, I am *not* looking for the ability to make `T` implement some *specific* interface.

Someone may try to mark this question as a duplicate of "[Force generic interface implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600696/force-generic-interface-implementation-in-c-sharp)". Here are the reasons why I believe it is worth not marking my question a duplicate:

1. That question is over 8 years old
2. The question was resolved when the person posting an answer discovered that the person posting the question actually wanted to know how to implement a *specific* interface
3. If this is not possible through constraints, there may be a workaround

---

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm trying to create multiple custom JSON converters using [Json.NET's JsonConverter Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).

```
public class Converter<T,M> : CustomCreationConverter<M>  
    where T : new()
{
    public override bool CanRead => base.CanRead;

    public override bool CanWrite => base.CanWrite;

    public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
    {
        return base.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    public override M Create(System.Type objectType)
    {
        return new T(); //Cannot implicity convert type 'T' to 'M'
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }
}
```

I could do the above or `public class MyClassConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IMyClass>{}` for every class I need a converter for. Just trying to keep things DRY!

Comment: Why does it matter if the type is a class or an interface? What I mean by the question is that knowing why it matters might tell us what you're hoping to accomplish using that knowledge, and we might be in a better position to suggest appropriate alternatives.

Comment: Contraints in generic are meant to achieve a functionality, how does it matter where they come from till the point rules are obeyed. You haven't explained what specific thing which an interface achieve in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A constraint that specified that T could be cast as M would also suffice in my specific circumstance.

It is possible to make a constraint where T must be derived from the type specified by another argument.

```cs
where T : M
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Also, in case anyone else stumbles across this, this information can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters. I found it just after you answered.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you have asked, with this kind of generic constraint how would you ensure M is always an interface thus T is always an interface. Generics always remain compile time verification, so nothing new will happen over run-time

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I didn't ask that T always be an interface, just that it implements M. M is what I wanted to be an interface. This answer requires that T be an implementation of M, meaning that M must be an interface or a base class. You are correct that this "doesn't answer the question" because it doesn't specifically force M to be an interface, but it would be useful for anyone else wanting the answer to this question.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect here M needn't be an interface / base class, it can also be same class a T when it comes to generic constraints, thus the issue remains as is you cannot guarantee its anything base. This means T and M can be same class and code will not complain

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) on the `where` generic type constraint tells you which constraints you can specify.

> The where clause in a generic definition specifies constraints on the types that are used as arguments for type parameters in a generic type, method, delegate, or local function. Constraints can specify interfaces, base classes, or require a generic type to be a reference, value or unmanaged type. They declare capabilities that the type argument must possess.

Given that, I believe the answer to your question is no, there is no way to specific that a generic type parameter be any interface.

Comment: Thanks, I did read the documentation before posting. Microsoft's documentation isn't always comprehensive, though.

Comment: Documentation is indeed clear, it clearly states what can comprise of a constraint and since there's no way to define "any interface", so there's no way to use it

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The linked documentation is not a comprehensive list of possible constraints.